# what parameters are used in catch of try-catch block in c++?

Tags: c++

I read a code which uses `try-catch` block.
Here is the part of the code:

```
class powers {
int x;

public:
powers() { x = 0; }
powers(int n) { x = n; }
};

int main() 
{
    powers *p;

    try {
        p = new powers[5]; 
    } 
    catch (bad_alloc xa) {
        cout << "Allocation Failure\n"; 
        return 1;
    }
}
```

I assume try is trying something and catch is catching any mismatch or failure in the try statement.
But what parameters are used in the catch?

Comment: Are you familiar with the use of `try` and `catch` in other contexts?

Comment: nope, i just encountered it in c++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`try` is a statement, so it can appear anywhere a statement can appear. It is designed to allow you to handle exceptions.

```
try
{
    //this code may throw!
}
```

After `try` block, there must be **one or more** handling blocks (or simply: handlers), that are defined as `catch` block:

```
catch(const std::exception& e)
{
}
catch(const MyException& e)
{
}
...
```

Formal parameter of `catch` block determines, what types of exceptions can be caught (and causes this block to be entered).

> When an exception of type `E` is thrown by any statement in compound-statement (`try` block), it is matched against the types of the formal parameters `T` of each catch-clause (`catch` block) [...], in the order in which the catch clauses are listed. The exception is a match if any of the following is true:
>
> - `E` and `T` are the same type (ignoring top-level cv-qualifiers on `T`)
> - `T` is an lvalue-reference to (possibly cv-qualified) `E`
> - `T` is an unambiguous public base class of `E`
> - `T` is a reference to an unambiguous public base class of `E`
> - `T` is a (possibly cv-qualified) pointer or a reference to a const pointer (since C++14), and `E` is also a pointer, which is implicitly convertible to `T`
> - `T` is a pointer or a pointer to member or a reference to a const pointer (since C++14), while `E` is `std::nullptr_t`.

Source: [try-block](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/try_catch).

Answer (score -3):

Exceptions provide a way to react to exceptional circumstances (like runtime errors) in programs by transferring control to special functions called handlers.

To catch exceptions, a portion of code is placed under exception inspection. This is done by enclosing that portion of code in a try-block. When an exceptional circumstance arises within that block, an exception is thrown that transfers the control to the exception handler. If no exception is thrown, the code continues normally and all handlers are ignored

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/exceptions/